# Mis codigos se volvieron 0000000

Tags: sublimetext3

Buen dia, Tengo un problema con mi archivo, el dia de ayer accidentalmente elimine una parte de mi codigo, guarde y cerre el sublimetext3, Lo hice sin pensar en que no podria recuperar la parte eliminada con un `ctrl-Z`, Pero bueno instalae un programa para recuperar versiones anteriores de archivos, Encontro lo que busco pero al abrirlo solo me me muestra lineas y lineas de `0000000000`.

Hay alguna forma de arreglarlo?
Hay alguna forma de recuperar la parte que borre?

Comment: la recuperación de archivos no es ciencia exacta. Cuando borras archivos, realmente quitas el apuntador al fragmento inicial en disco de la tabla de archivos. Ahí la recuperación puede buscar esos headers de archivos y tratar de reconstruirlos. Si modificaste un archivo, el apuntador posiblemente siga señalando el mismo fragmento inicial y haya cambiado sólo parte de los segmentos de espacio en disco usados (ya es más difícil recuperar una versión previa). Si tu sublime mantiene archivos temporales, puede que esos puedan recuperarse.

Comment: Si seguiste usando tu OS después de la modificación, los archivos eliminados (al menos algunos fragmentos de espacio en disco) son reutilizados por otros archivos y se pierde ese eslabon en la cadena, haciendo irrecuperable el contenido completo. Te sugiero usar un sistema de control de versión para reducir el impacto de estos inconvenientes.